# How do I rotate meshes around their local axes in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna

I have an object in my game that has a few meshes and when I try to rotate either of the meshes either way, it only rotates it around world axis, and not its local axis. I have a `rotation = Matrix.Identity` in a class constructor. Every mesh has this class attached to it. Then this class also contains methods:

```
...
public Matrix Transform{ get; set; }
public void Rotate(Vector3 newRot)
{
    rotation = Matrix.Identity;
    rotation *= Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(rotation.Up, MathHelper.ToRadians(newRot.X));
    rotation *= Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(rotation.Right, MathHelper.ToRadians(newRot.Y));
    rotation *= Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(rotation.Forward, MathHelper.ToRadians(newRot.Z));

    CreateMatrix();
}

private void CreateMatrix()
{
    Transform = Matrix.CreateScale(scale) * rotation * Matrix.CreateTranslation(Position);
}
...
```

And now the Draw() method:

```
foreach (MeshProperties mesh in model.meshes)
{
    foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Mesh.Effects)//Where Mesh is a ModelMesh that this class contains information about
    {
        effect.View = cam.view;
        effect.Projection = cam.projection;
        effect.World = mesh.Transform;
        effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
    }
    mesh.Mesh.Draw();
}
```

---

**EDIT:**
I am afraid either I screwed somewhere up, or your tehnique does not work, this is what I did. Whenever I move the whole object(Parent), I set its `Vector3 Position;` to that new value. I also set every MeshProperties `Vector3 Position;` to that value. And then inside `CreateMatrix()` of MeshProperties I did like so:

```
...
Transform = RotationMatrix * Matrix.CreateScale(x, y, z) * RotationMatrix * Matrix.CreateTranslation(Position) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(Parent.Position);
...
```

Where:

```
public void Rotate(Vector3 newRot)
{
    Rotation = newRot;
    RotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(Transform.Up,          MathHelper.ToRadians(Rotation.X)) * 
    Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(Transform.Forward, MathHelper.ToRadians(Rotation.Z)) * 
    Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(Transform.Right, MathHelper.ToRadians(Rotation.Y));
}
```

And `Rotation` is `Vector3`.
`RotationMatrix` and `Transform` are both set to `Matrix.Identity` in the constructor.

The problem is if I try to rotate around for example Y axis, he should rotate in a circle while "standing still". But he moves around while rotating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that, when I was exporting model as .FBX the pivot point wasnt in model centre. Thus making the model move while rotating.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely certain this is what you want. I'm assuming here you have an object, with some meshes and positions offset from the position and orientation of the main object position and you want to rotate the child object around its local axis relative to the parent.

```
Matrix.CreateTranslation(-Parent.Position) *                  //Move mesh back...
Matric.CreateTranslation(-Mesh.PositionOffset) *              //...to object space

Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(Mesh.LocalAxis, AngleToRotateBy) * //Now rotate around your axis
Matrix.CreateTranslation(Mesh.PositionOffset) *               //Move the mesh...
Matrix.CreateTranslation(Parent.Position);                    //...back to world space
```

Of course you usually store a transform matrix which transforms a mesh from object space to world space in one step, and you'd also store the inverse. You also store the mesh in object coordinates all the time and only move it into world coordinate for rendering. This would simplify things a little:

```
Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(Mesh.LocalAxis, AngleToRotateBy) * //We're already in object space, so just rotate
ObjectToWorldTransform *
Matrix.CreateTranslation(Parent.Position);
```

I think you could simply set Mesh.Transform in your example to this and be all set.

I hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: Actually, all of the meshes have the same position. I know it sounds weird, but it draws them correctly and not all in one place. I dont know how thats possible,any idea how? Btw could you pleease explain a bit what those variables represent:(**Mesh.LocalAxis** ,**objectToWorldTransform** and **Parent.Position**) ?

Comment: Well you said "rotates it around world axis, and not its local axis", so mesh.LocalAxis is whatever axis it is you want to rotate around! ObjectToWorldTransform is a matrix which transforms from object space to world space, i.e. scale * rotate * translate. Parent.Position is the position of the parent of a mesh, it sounded like you're using multiple meshes to represent one object, in which parent.Position would be the position of the object, rather than any specific mesh.